# How to use clock data in http request in android?

Tags: android, httprequest

I can't understand the working of this code. Please if anyone knows help me. The code is given below:

```
val clockData: String = CPU.getClockData(
        this,
        TextUtils.join("", arrayList2).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
        0
    )
```

I could not understand the code. This clockData will be used as field in http request. Anyone knows its working?

Comment: I don't know CPU Class, but "TextUtils.join("", arrayList2).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))" joins "strings" one after the other and after this concatenated string it converts the final String to byte[].

Comment: what is `CPU`? this class doesn't belong to Android framework, you are importing it somehow... use ctrl-click (or middle click) on method for inspecting what happens in it

Comment: CPU is from other pacakge, com.yxcorp.gifshow.util.CPU.

Comment: I am getting error in http request. i.e. failed to verify the signature. Is the given question code can generate the signature or what. Any comments?